# Issue implementing MVC in board game - MouseListener now only works for whole grid, not individual cells

Tags: java, model-view-controller, mouselistener

I am trying to implement a game using MVC design. However, I'm running into a few problems. Rather than ask for a plethora of help on MVC (which I'm rather enjoying experimenting with, even though much of it is unsucessful!), I'm struggling a bit with my listeners right now.

I have an abstract grid class that looks like this:

```
public abstract class ViewAbstractGrid extends JPanel {

    private final int GRID_SIZE = 10;
    private ViewCell[][] cellArray = new ViewCell[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE];
    private ViewCell currentCell;

    public ViewAbstractGrid() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        setLayout(new GridLayout(GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE));
        for (int x = 0; x < GRID_SIZE; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < GRID_SIZE; y++) {
                currentCell = new ViewCell(x, y);
                cellArray[x][y] = currentCell;
                add(currentCell);
            }
        }

    public ViewCell[][] getCellArray() {
        return cellArray;
    }

    public abstract void addListener(MouseListener listener);
}
```

In my original design for the game, as the ViewCells were being implemented I created a MouseListener for them, so each ViewCell had its own panel. However, I've tried to remove this logic to a Controller class, so that rather than each ViewCell having its own listener, the entire grid had a single listener.
This is the ViewCell class:

```
public class ViewCell extends JPanel {
    private final int CELL_SIZE = 1;
    public static Color backgroundColor = new Color(105, 120, 105);
    private int xPos;
    private int yPos;

    public ViewCell(int xPos, int yPos) {
        setOpaque (true);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(CELL_SIZE));
        setBackground(backgroundColor);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE));
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;   
    }

    public Color getCellGUIColor() {
        return backgroundColor;
    }

    public int getXPos() {
        return xPos;
    }

    public int getYPos() {
        return yPos;
    }
}
```

AS you can see, it extends JPanels, meaning the grid I create is effectively filled with 100 JPanels. People (including on this forum) have told me I could consider using JButtons instead, but originally at least I found the JPanels easier to work with.
I then have a concrete Player Grid class that extends the ViewAbstractGrid:

```
public class ViewPlayerGrid extends ViewAbstractGrid {
    private LogicGrid playerGridLogic;
    private ViewAbstractGrid playerGrid;
    private int xPos;
    private int yPos;
    private int numberOfPlayerShipsPlaced = 0;

    public ViewPlayerGrid(LogicGrid playerGridLogic) {
        this.playerGridLogic = playerGridLogic;
    }

    public void addListener(MouseListener listener) {
        this.addMouseListener(listener);
    }
```

There are two of these concrete subclasses - one for the computer, one for the player. I have only included the player one for brevity.

Finally, I have a Controller class that looks like this:

```
public class GameController {
    private LogicGrid playerGridLogic;
    private ViewAbstractGrid playerGrid;
    private int xPos;
    private int yPos;
    private int numberOfPlayerShipsPlaced = 0;
    private int numberOfComputerShipsPlaced = 0;

    public GameController(LogicGrid playerGridLogic, ViewAbstractGrid playerGrid) {
        this.playerGridLogic = playerGridLogic;
        this.playerGrid = playerGrid;
        playerGrid.addListener(new PlayerGridListener());
    }

    class PlayerGridListener implements MouseListener {
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        //I know this looks wrong, but I forgot that the x and y axis on a Java grid start at the top left, not bottom left. Just go with it for now!
        // Dividing by 30 as dimensions are 300 by 300. This returns results that that are between 0 and 9.
        yPos = e.getX()/30;
        xPos = e.getY()/30;

        switch(numberOfPlayerShipsPlaced) {
        case 0:
            if ((yPos + 5) <= 10) {
                for (int y = yPos; y < yPos + 5; y++) {
                    playerGrid.getCellArray()[xPos][y].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                }
            }
            else {
                for (int y = yPos; y < 10; y++) {
                    playerGrid.getCellArray()[xPos][y].setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

As can be seen, this class gets a little messy towards the end. I have removed lots of logic to try and make the code shorter. The game is for Battleships and the reason for the little snippet of code above was to try and detect whether the user had selected a cell on the grid that could accommodate a horizontal ship five cells long. If it could, the square turned green - if it couldn't, it turned red.

I have "models" as well, but haven't included them as they aren't necessary for the GUI design.

Basically, the problem is this: When I originally created all this code and have the listeners built directly into the View, I couldn't get the two boards to communicate with each other. I also realised I wasn't following good coding practice and tried to break my code down into a MVC pattern.

An issue that has followed from this is that I have a listener now for the entire grid. The problem with this is that when I place my mouse on a square, it will change colour once for the duration of the time the mouse is anywhere in the grid. Once that initial square (or squares) have changed color, no other square in the grid will change colour until the mouse has left the grid and come back again.

This is no good to me - I need the squares to change colour as the mouse is moving across them. Could anybody suggest how I could do this given my current design? Is the only way to go back to having listeners for each panel? And if so, does that mean my listeners must be in the view class, as opposed to the Controller class? Additionally, if anyone wants to chuck any pointers to me above improving my code design (or keeping my questions shorter!), feel free!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies - after that huge long post I've figured out what to do (I think!)

In the ViewPlayerGrid class, I've changed the addListener method. It was originally:

```
public void addListener(MouseListener listener) {
    this.addMouseListener(listener);
}
```

It's now:

```
public void addListener(MouseListener listener) {
    cellArray = getCellArray();
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
            cellArray[x][y].addMouseListener(listener);
        }
    }
}
```

By doing this, in the GameController, I can change the way I am finding the coordinates of each cell. Originally, the GameController's inner class - PlayerGridListener - had a mouseEntered method like this:

```
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    yPos = e.getX()/30;
    xPos = e.getY()/30;
    // Switch statement and rest of code
```

By adding the listener to each cell, I have changed it to this:

```
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    ViewCell test = (ViewCell) e.getSource();
    xPos = test.getXPos();
    yPos = test.getYPos();
    // Switch statement and rest of code
```

Now I can access each ViewCell individually and use the get methods defined in the ViewCell class to manipulate each of them. Hurrah!

Comment: Good job figuring out your own problem.  As a tip for future work - if you need to track the pointer's position as it moves around inside your Component, what you need to do is add a MouseMotionListener to your Component; this gives you mouseMoved() and mouseDragged() events that get called whenever the mouse moves over your component without/with a button pressed, respectively.

Comment: I am setting up my grids so that when the user places their cursor on a cell, a 'tail' of cells either horizontal or vertical of it are highlighted as well. Once they place their first ship (five cells long), only four cells are highlighted and so on. As they drag their cursor across the board, the range of cells are either green if they are in range or red if they aren't. ARe you then saying that mouseMoved() and mouseDragged() are the way to go and I should replace my MouseListener with a MouseMotionListener()?

Comment: For what you're doing right now, either solution (your current MouseEntered() on the cell, or a MotionListener on the board) are fine, it sounds like.  I was just mentioning the alternate approach so that you were aware of it.  If you wanted to have multi-cell operations (e.g. user clicks on cell A and drags over to cell B, then releases), it may be easier to use the MotionListener.